# How to catch unknown number of whitespaces in a Python regex?

Tags: python, regex, replace, operators, conditional-statements

I would like to create a small Python regex in order to replace similar strings into several text files.

Problem is that those files may be a bit different in terms of whitespaces.
For example first text file looks like this :

```
myString=${string_1}/${string_2}
```

But second text file contains the following string :

```
myString  = ${string_1}/${string_2}
```

How can I write a regex that takes both string in both files and then replace `myString` with `myString=${string_1}_${string_2}/string3` no matter how many whitespaces there are (let's assume we do not know the exact number).

So far, my regex looks like this :

```
temp_dir = tempfile.gettempdir()
temp_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, 'temp_file_name')

fin = open(path, 'r')
fout = open(temp_path, 'w')
#Beginning of the regex
for line in fin:
    string = re.sub("myString=${string_1}/${string_2}", "myString=${string_1}_${string_2}/string3", line)
    fout.write(string)

fin.close()
fout.close()

return temp_path
```

As you can see, I do not know how to match the possibility with whitespaces within the `re.sub()` method.

Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks.

Comment: Search for `r'myString\s*=\s*'` and replace with `'myString='`

Comment: @anubhava how about taking into account the rest of the string for the Search part ? `r'myString\s*=\s*${string_1}/${string_2}'` does not seem to be working ..

Comment: You need to escape `$` and possibly `{` and `}` in regex